# Cannot get data after login ASP.net session key method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, api, webforms

The site I'm building is done using AngularJS front-end and Windows webforms in the back-end.
I believe the Authorization done through ASP.net Session Key.

So you  create a AngularJS Post method to "login" and then you execute another method to "getuserdata".

**Login:**

```
{ "method": "logintheconsumer",
"email":MyEmail,
"password":MyPassword}
```

**Get User Details:**

```
{ "method": "getconsumerdetails" }
```

This works correctly using POSTMAN API App, but when I implement the code in JavaScript/AngularJS, it throws error response.

I have not implemented any other code structure. What Am I missing ... ?

Comment: "What Am I missing ... ?"     Details about the error, and the code that is causing it, would be a great help.

Comment: well it gets Error response, not Success response. you know the promise goes to Error response. Does it make sense ? I think what happens is when the first Post is done, it should create a sessionID and save in my browser. 
So when I make the second Post to ge the details, it checks the session, session is ok, it authorize to send the data. But in here, it cannot do it it cannot identify me. I think that's the problem. not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be an issue of server side. You need to make sure CORS in Webconfig is allowed to access their Service. This may work.

```
<httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
```